# Android: strange behavior with random position of textview on FrameLayout

Tags: android, textview, position, fragment, android-framelayout

So far I've created an app that display two `TextView` in a `FrameLayout` inside a `Fragment`, I have a button to update the text of these `TextView`s and the position according to the text. 
Now, the text is correctly updated and it displays the desired position, but it never matches the actual position I see and obtain at the end of the function (see below).

Here's the Function:

```
public void randomTextPos(View v) {
    FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragm_root_layout);
    TextView child = null;
    Log.i("size", "size = " + rootView.getWidth() + " " + rootView.getHeight());

    position[0] = (int) map((float) (Math.random()), 0, 1, 0,
            rootView.getWidth());
    position[1] = (int) map((float) (Math.random()), 0, 1, 0,
            rootView.getHeight());

    Log.i("onClick", "TextView at pos " + position[0] + " "
            + position[1]);

    if (idChild == 0) { // choose the child textview
        child = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.first_text);
    } else {
        child = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.second_text);
    }

    String mystring = Float.toString(position[0]) + "\n"
            + Float.toString(position[1]);
    char[] mystringtochar = mystring.toCharArray();
    child.setText(mystringtochar, 0, mystringtochar.length);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            child.getWidth(), child.getHeight());
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.leftMargin = (int) position[0];
    params.topMargin = (int) position[1];
    child.setLayoutParams(params);
    child.invalidate(); 
    rootView.invalidate();

    String myactualposition = "Left = " + Integer.toString(child.getLeft())
            + " Top " + Integer.toString(child.getTop());
    Log.i("Position!!!", myactualposition);// here I see that the getLeft 
        doesn't match with position[0]

    idChild = idChild == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

and Here's the function I use to map the values from Math.random(), this shouldn't be a problem since I already successfully used it:

```
public static float map(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min,
        float out_max) {
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

and Here's the Layout of the `Fragment`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragm_root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/first_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="first text\n view" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/second_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="second text\n view" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance, I'm sure this is something simple and I cannot see it.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the textview moving but not to the correct position?

Comment: Exactly. It seem like there's no relation between the given coordinates and the effective position. sometimes they also disappear from the screen.